# Page Expired if POST method (Laravel 5.5)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My routes

```
Route::middleware('auth.basic')->group(function(){


Route::post('/', 'DeliveryController@calc')->name('delivery');

Route::post('pickup/', 'DeliveryController@getPickup');

Route::post('pec_pickup/', 'DeliveryController@getPecPickupPoint');});
```

when i try send request with postman i got "Page Expired". But if i replace all routes with GET - all ok.

Comment: What error you are getting? You are not setting http verb to `POST`, did you you check this ?

Comment: are you sending access token in your post ?

Answer (score 0):

Use 
 **{{ csrf_field() }}** just bellow your form definition.

This will send a token to Controller to ensure that the request it has been made from your site.

This is a security enforcement for POST method, which should be use for create, delete, update on your models.